# how can i boot Oppo a12 into fastboot mode

Tags: rooting

I am not able to boot my oppo a12 into fast mode. Because i want to root my oppo a12 withot going fastbbot mode it is not possible .so please help me

Comment: you can't unlock bootloader on Oppo A12 because Oppo does not support unlocking. There is however some hack but i doubt it is for A12 https://easy-firmware.com/index.php?a=downloads&b=file&id=338154